# PostgreSQL 9.5 IF-THEN-ELSE inside FUNCTION not available?

Tags: postgresql

### My problem

While trying to `CREATE` a `FUNCTION` in my **PostgreSQL** database, version **9.5**, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 3:   IF strpos(trem_outcome, 'VALIDATED') = 0 THEN
```

Here's the `FUNCTION` I'm talking about:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countValid(outcome text) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF strpos(outcome, 'VALIDATED') = 0 THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        RETURN 0;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

Looks like the `IF-THEN-ELSE` control statements aren't available to me here, although I'm inside a `FUNCTION` right?

What am I missing?

### Some context

I ultimately wanna `sum(countValid())` of a huge set of data, like follows:

```sql
SELECT
    table1.tbl1_pk,
    count(table2.tbl2_outcome) as registered,
    sum(countValid(table2.tbl2_outcome)) as validated
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.tbl2_tbl1_fk = table1.tbl1_pk
GROUP BY table1.tbl1_pk;
```

Where my tables are like:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                 table1                |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| tbl1_pk (int) | tbl1_other_crap (w/e) |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| 1             | ...                   |
| 2             | ...                   |
| 3             | ...                   |
+---------------+-----------------------+

+------------------------------------------------+
|                    table2                      |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
| tbl2_pk | tbl2_tbl1_fk          | tbl2_outcome |
| (int)   | (int -> tbl1.tbl1_pk) | (text)       |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
| 1       | 1                     | VALIDATED    |
| 2       | 1                     | FLUNKED      |
| 3       | 3                     | VALIDATED    |
| 4       | 3                     | VALIDATED    |
| 5       | 1                     | FLUNKED      |
| 6       | 2                     | VALIDATED    |
| 7       | 3                     | VALIDATED    |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

I'd expect the following result set:

```
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| tbl1_pk (int) | registered (int) | validated (int) |
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1             | 3                | 1               |
| 2             | 1                | 1               |
| 3             | 3                | 3               |
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

### Minimal reproducible example

I can reproduce my issue on an even simpler function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countValid(outcome text) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF 1 = 1 THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        RETURN 0;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

... which triggers:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 3:   IF 1 = 1 THEN
```

I'm open to entirely different approaches, although I'd much rather have my work executed in a single query.

Comment: @IldarMusin That was it. I love you `:)`

Comment: Please delete your question. Simple typos should not hang around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need that function. Just use

```
count(table2.tbl2_outcome = 'VALIDATED' or null)
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try it later but that does seem reasonable.